# How to push information to active directory with ASP

Tags: asp-classic, active-directory

Can someone point me in the right direction for information on how to push data to Active Directory from Classic ASP?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways this can be done from classic ASP.

- Use [ADO with ADSI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746471(v=vs.85).aspx)
- Use the [ADSI Objects of LDAP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa772208(v=vs.85).aspx)

Here's a sample from [Modifying an ADSI Object from ADO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746395(v=vs.85).aspx)

```
'Replace department for all users in OU=sales.
Set con = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
con.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"

Set command = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set command.ActiveConnection = con

command.CommandText = "SELECT AdsPath, cn FROM 'LDAP://OU=Sales,DC=Fabrikam,DC=com' WHERE objectClass = 'user'"

command.Properties("searchscope") = ADS_SCOPE_ONELEVEL
Set rs = command.Execute
While Not rs.EOF
    Set usr = GetObject(rs.Fields("AdsPath").Value)
    usr.Put "department", "1001"
    usr.SetInfo
    rs.MoveNext
Wend
```

Here's a sample from the article [Getting Started with ASP for ADSI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa705944(VS.85).aspx).

```
<%@ Language=VBScript %>
<%
' Get the inputs.
containerName = Request.Form("inpContainer")
' Validate compName before using.

If Not ("" = containerName) Then
  ' Bind to the object.
  adsPath = "LDAP://" & containerName
  Set comp = GetObject(adsPath)

  ' Write the ADsPath of each of the child objects.
  Response.Write("<p>Enumeration:</p>")
  For Each obj in comp
    Response.Write(obj.ADsPath + "<BR>")
  Next
End If
%>
```